# Drop all tables from database command apart from named few

Tags: sql-server, drop-table

I have been looking for a command to drop all tables from a single database apart from a few tables without doing something like this:

```
DROP table table1, table2, table3
```

and ignoring the tables I do not want to drop. Is there a better way to do this by dropping all tables apart from the few that I do not want to drop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using such a CURSOR, you can print or execute all the DROP statements:

```
DECLARE cur_del CURSOR FOR
    SELECT QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id))+'.'+QUOTENAME(name) 
    FROM sys.tables
    WHERE name NOT IN ('x', 'y', 'z', ...);

OPEN cur_del;

DECLARE @table sysname;
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max);

FETCH NEXT FROM cur_del
INTO @table;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @sql =  'DROP TABLE ' + @table + ';';
    PRINT @sql;
    --EXEC sp_executesql @sql;

    FETCH NEXT FROM cur_del INTO @table
END

CLOSE cur_del;
DEALLOCATE cur_del;
```

This query only prints the DROP statements out. You can uncomment the EXEC line if you want DROP them.

The first `SELECT` does not look for anything at all aside from what is included in the `IN(...)` and you have to make sure it does not match more table than what you really want to delete.

In the WHERE clause, you can replace `name` (table name) by the fully qualify name with schema using `QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id))+'.'+QUOTENAME(name) NOT IN ('schema.x', ...)`.
If there is only one schema, you can add `AND SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) = 'xxx'` and keep `name`.

It also does not look for dependencies which may prevent DROP.

If there are Foreign Keys, you can first DROP them using a similar cursor along with this query:

```
SELECT 'ALTER TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME(f.schema_id))+'.'+ QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(o.object_id)) + ' DROP CONSTRAINT ' +  QUOTENAME(f.name) 
FROM sys.foreign_keys f
INNER JOIN sys.objects o ON f.parent_object_id = o.object_id
WHERE OBJECT_NAME(f.referenced_object_id) NOT IN ('x', 'y', 'z')
    AND  OBJECT_NAME(o.object_id) NOT IN ('x', 'y', 'z');
```